# How to clear the Android default browser cache/cookies/Location Prefererence programatically?

Tags: caching

I want to clear Android default browser cache/cookies/Location Prefererence programatically. Or the source code for the Privacy Security in the Settings of the Browser App. Please help...

Thanks,
Centhil